# Can't track what is changing a variable mysteriously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with a grid layout where I put my instantiated clones of prefab text objects.

Each instance of the visual timer representations have an attached timer script.

And a button that adds those text objects to the list (panel):

[image: Screenshot from live version of the prototype]

When my button is pressed, I call the `StartTimer` function from the new timer (I left out all similar code for instantiating the research name text):

```
public void AddResearch() {
    ...
    float timeInSeconds = (float) Random.Range(5, 16);
    ...
    GameObject newTimerObject = (GameObject) Instantiate(
        researchTimerPrefab,
        researchList.transform.position,
        researchList.transform.rotation);
    newTimerObject.transform.SetParent(researchList.transform);
    ...
    newTimerObject.GetComponent<ResearchTimer> ().StartTimer (timeInSeconds);
    ...
}
```

And in the `ResearchTimer` script class, where the `StartTimer(float)` resides, I get the problem I'm trying to locate:

```
public class ResearchTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float timeRemaining;

    private Text visualText;
    private bool isStarted; //This is the variable I don't understand

    void Start () {
        visualText = GetComponent<Text> ();
        //I initiate it to false here because
        //I don't want update called before the timer starts.
        isStarted = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        //Here, isStarted is always false after setting it to true "StartTimer"
        if (!isStarted) return;

        //code to update text representation of the timer
        ... 
    }

    public void StartTimer(float timeInSeconds) {
        timeRemaining = timeInSeconds;
        isStarted = true;

        //When I set a breakpoint here, the "isStarted" variable is changed to true,
        //but the next time the Update function runs, it's false again.
        //That is the part I don't understand

        InvokeRepeating ("decreaseTimeRemaining", 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    void decreaseTimeRemaining()
    {
        //If I set isStarted here, it shows correctly (as per screenshot),
        //but then it won't be set before the first second has passed
        isStarted = true;
        timeRemaining--;
    }

    ...
}
```

The `isStarted` is not set anywhere else in the code. Why is this happening?

---

On a side note, I learned I don't seem to need the variable, but I'm still curious why it happened.

Comment: Did you know that isStarted will be `false` by default to begin with?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: What I'm actually asking is why `isStarted` is still false after calling `StartTimer()`. I know `Start()` is called way before I ever call `StartTimer()` so I don't understand why/how it is set to false again after that. Does that help?

Comment: Good point. That's my error and a quite embarassing one. I must be confused. Sorry.

Comment: this sort of problem is easily solved.  MAKING ABSOLUTELY SURE YOU ARE INCLUDING >>>>ALL<<< FILES, find all mentions of "isStarted" in ALL your text files.  (2) using Debug.Log (NOT breakpoints) put in a clear Debug.Log("description of location " +isStarted) at EVERY mention of isStarted. "description of location" MUST BE different for EACH use of Debug.Log.  You will have the solution in seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're spamming the comments here. I know how to use `Debug.Log()`. And as you pointed out, isStarted is a private variable, so why does other files matter? Here's [every mention of isStarted](http://i.imgur.com/JmcOZWP.png) which I already showed you in the above question. Discussing `++` vs `+=1` or `v = v+1` neither seems relevant to the discussion at all. Please talk about this elsewhere.

Comment: ok, if you put in three Debug.Log where you use it the three times, and Play, and watch the console you'll find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ResearchTimer` class place the `isStarted = false` in the `Awake` method.

When your `newTimerObject` is instantiated the `Awake` method for each component on that object is called, but the `Start` is not called until the first update has been executed.

So, in your case the `Awake` method is called (if there was one), `StartTimer` is then called which sets `isStarted` to `true`, but when the next update is executed the `Start` method is called which then sets it to `false`.

If you initialise `isStarted` in `Awake`, rather than `Start`, then it should be called just after `newTimerObject` is instantiated and just before you call `StartTime'.

```
void Awake () {
    visualText = GetComponent<Text> ();
    //I initiate it to false here because
    //I don't need updates before the timer starts.
    isStarted = false;
}
```

This is going from memory, so can confirm this in your instance. But, the following link explains when `Awake` and `Start` are called.

[Unity - Execution Order of Event Functions](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Here's kind of an ascii-art diagram of what happens in a frame.

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|
|
|
|  all your various code runs here
|  you instantiate something .. Awake runs
|  all your various code runs here
|  you instantiate something .. Awake runs
|  you instantiate something .. Awake runs
|  all your various code runs here
|
|  unity does many things here, drawing, physics, etc etc
|  unity does many things here, drawing, physics, etc etc
|  unity does many things here, drawing, physics, etc etc
|
|_ _ _ _ _ _ 
|  all of the Starts are run at once here
|_ _ _ _ _ 
|
| next frame begins...
```

You can use this to your advantage as `Start` is only run **"after all your own code"**. You have no clue what order your code runs in, **but**, you know `Start` always runs "after all your code, everywhere". Say you are making a spaceship, an enemy ship, and a cargo ship. Once `Start` runs, you know that **all three** are there.

Comment: **Exactly correct.**  As I mentioned to the OP, if they simply add a Debug line, one would see clearly that the "isStarted = false" is called **after** the StartTimer call is made.

Comment: Indeed, as someone mentioned in the first comment, "Did you know that `isStarted` will be `false` by default to begin with?" it's perhaps more sound to not bother "re-initializing it" to the default value. but in any event MotoSV has completely explained the problem. it's critical to know that `Awake` runs when the object is instantiated, but Start only runs "when the runloop starts" (later).

Comment: This is exactly why I included the first paragraph in the question, which @JoeBlow removed. I thought it might be something about event lifecycle.  I guess I should have explained how I saw the event cycle to begin with, to make it easier for someone to correct me. Honestly I still don't understand it entirely, and I can't test it right now because I I'm having a different error that makes me unable to run the program at the moment. I think it was because I renamed the prefabs and thereby destroyed some meta data. I'll revert to last time I saved and let you know when I can test it.

Comment: you can revert edits anytime, I deleted this **I wish I knew how to be more specific, but I'm quite confident that my problem comes from a lack of understanding of some structure parts work in Unity.**

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes I know, but being the Unity newb here, I don't want to revert edits before I'm sure it's wrong. I only have 10 edits before it turns into a wiki article and that's passed quickly in an "edit war". And from my perspective, we were definitely having controversies. And in my prior comment I was speaking about reverting my unity files, not reverting your edit of my question.

Comment: I find your answer confusing, but after fiddling around with it for some time, I think I understand the difference between Awake and Start now. At least for this context. Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is very clear, especially the first two sentences.

Comment: @JoeBlow Good, that's also how I understand it now. Before asking this question, I thought `Start()` did was `Awake()` does. I must have misunderstood the tutorials then. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow This is why I disagree: The first sentence is an "order", not an explanation. Therefore, it only makes sense if you a) understand it already or b) don't care about understanding it and just want the solution. The second paragraph was difficult me to grasp because of grammar. But if I imagined a pause between "instantiated" and "the" it makes a bit more sense. But since I thought `Update()` was called way before I called ´StartTimer()` I would misunderstand this without further explanation.

Comment: it is very subtle and very few people understand it.  I edited the excellent answer to make it even more excellenter.  Additionally I urge you to **not** initialize the boolean, as it defaults to `false` anyways!

Comment: @JoeBlow But it doesn't matter now. I don't see the point in arguing further, since we disagree, and the problem seems solved anyway. I'm wiser from the experience anyhow. It might not be great for future readers, but that's what happens I guess.

Comment: JoeBlow: Please do not modify an answer that has already been accepted. If you feel the answer is incorrect or could be improved upon, then please post your own solution and, if that is considered a more precise answer, then Aske B has the option to accept that over this answer.

Comment: Hi Moto -- it's totally OK to roll back edits if you don't like them, and you should do that!!!  Rock on.